# vagrant/puphpet: adding a custom nginx default conf file

Tags: nginx, vagrant, puphpet

i use [Puphpet](https://puphpet.com/) to create a local testing vagrant /VM servers and my question is:

I ssh into the VM to change my **etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf** config file, but every now and then when either i have to to or choose to i destroy the said vm to mainly re-create or because of issue, i need to repeat the above process of having to update a few config files.

Is there a way say within the vagrantfile or the comman.yaml (puphpet) file to actually add this automatically so i don't need to do this at all.

Comment: @juantreminio your answer should really be a comment.  But basically the file has a lot of commented out details and we also need to add some added items after the inital set up we have to ssh into it and use vim at present to alter it

Answer (score 1):

You could create a shell script in `puphpet/files/exec-once`[[1]](https://puphpet.com/#server) to replace your **default.conf** file.

Comment: Do you have a tutorial for this? :) (NGINX)

Comment: @wiesson Unfortunately I've switched to a custom vagrant+puppet script as I had some issues with puphpet (namely php 5.3 on ubuntu 12.04 is not supported, but we still use it in our stack).

Comment: Thanks anyway. While searching for examples, I figured it out by myself :)